# Unity 3D get camera rotated angle

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my unity app initially I have set the camera in a certain position. Later I change the camera position dynamically. After doing that I need to find the angle/rotation it rotated and  another object needs to  be rotated by the same angle but in the opposite direction.
I have two questions.
1.How do I find the angle the camera moved?
2.How do I rotate the game object by the same value but in the opposite direction.
I tried things like target.transform.Rotate( Camera.main.transform.position - cameraNewPos); and also googled a lot but couldn't find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always compare the current transform.rotation to its original value before you made the change to see the different. Then, apply the same change (in reverse) to your other object.

On camera:
var delta = transform.rotation - _originalRotation;

On that Object:
transform.rotation = transform.rotation - delta;

Comment: @derHugo if `Quaternion` is hard to work with, why not convert it to euler?

Answer (score 0):

If your camera is at position P1, and orientation Q1 at start, and P2, Q2, after you moved it, you can find the translation T and rotation R that goes from 1 to 2 using (using transform.rotation and transform.position, which represent the world transform of you object, independent of its hierarchy) :

R = Q1.Inverse() * Q2

T = P2 - P1

Note that you can't substract quaternions.

Then you can simply move your other object accordingly.

Obj.position = initialCameraPosition - T

Obj.rotation = initialCameraRotation * R (or R.Inverse() if you want to mirror the rotation as well)

Answer (score 0):

So:
If you want to get the amount of rotation applied from a time to a time, you could just save the data from the begin and then substract the end rotation - begin rotation.

```
Vector3 iRotation;
Vector3 amountRot;
void Start() { // for example
    iRotation = obj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
}

void Update() { // at some point you want
    if (sth) amountRot = obj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles - iRotation;

    obj2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-obj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles); // rotate opposite
```